# Use CocoaHTTPServer on iOS to share files?

Tags: ios, file-sharing, cocoahttpserver

I like to know how to share files from iOS with CocoaHTTPServer over WiFi. Is this even possible, or isn't this possible with CocoaHTTPServer?

I already made it to share the default html site via WiFi, but I cant make it to show the whole directory. I either like to share the apps document directory or the root file system.

Comment: What do you mean by "share"? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @Linuxios With share I mean download and upload, so download from web server to other device or upload from other device to web server.

Comment: Do you have a server? What does it run? Do you have the code for it?

Comment: @Linuxios The server is running on my iOs device, its CocoaHTTPServer. https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer I just want to access my file system and upload, download files to and from it from another Computer. It isnt a Local Webserver running on Linux or windows

Comment: In that case, you need a way to tell your computer the ip of your I device, and they need to be on the same wifi network.

Comment: Yeah, I have the IP of my iPhone and the Port of the server, I can display the index.html, but I dont know how to share files

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I used the standard code to run the server. Have you ever used CocoaHTTPServer before? I think you dont understand me

Comment: Hi @DavidG. Did you work it out? If you did can you please share

Answer (score 0):

When you say upload and download files by sharing sounds very suspicious. Sounds more like your illegally spying on someone’s device and stealing there files without them knowing. There is no reason to put cocoahttpserver on top of an iOS server. That’s just a fancy way to sinc a device and see everything they are doing.  That actually happens to me. Cocoa does not come built in on iOS devices. It has to be physically installed.